# Managing Point in Time Data in a SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm currently using `Adjacency List Model` with my hierarchical data in my SQL database and I'm going to change it to a `Nested Set Model` to eliminate my recursive processing when I have multiple levels.

This data is used to represent a tree filled with high level objects that we want to represent and use in other part of our system. We want to use this for to increase the integrity of the data, universal definition and such.. We're allowing users, in a controlled user interface, to add new objects, new children to existing objects and to move stuff around to build the `-->`

**real and complete vision of our data world**.

- The problem :

  We want to keep track (with `point in time`) of where and what was
  the data before being changed. We want to be able to produce report
  on what was the data and what is it now.

  Right now, to do that, we're using a `Chronological Table` that is
  just filled with new entries consisting of the same objects but with
  different data, start date and end date. So each time an object
  (node) is moved under a new parent, of it's data is changed (e.g.
  description, name, etc.) we add a new entry in the table. Thus, the
  table is going to be just awfully big, and will probably contain
  redundancy..
- Why :

  I'm not sure that having redundancy, and a massive set of data in my
  Chronological Table is a efficient way to do this.

  Do you guys had to deal with that kind of data before? What did you
  do? What do you think?

> **I want to know if I could implement this another way? Is there a better way of managing data changes through time?**

**[Edit]**

Example :

Each node has a set of columns (around 20) (properties) than can be used to help people with the definitions, help text, parent, sort, or even just the name of the node itself.

So I need to track that data, I need to be able to know where it was in the hierarchy before it's changed place, I need to know its name before, I need to know everything on this node.. But if something changes, I need to add a new entry with a new valid start date for the same node but all the data will be repeating if it didn't change. So if it changed parent, the parent reference gets updated but everything else is redundancy.

**Chronological Table**

[image: Chronological Table]
So `ID` is the unique id for the chronological and `UID` for the object itself. We also planned on adding all the text values for a node to the Chronological Table.

So Imagine over 5 years if the object (UID) 15 changed like 1000 times, 1000 new entries.

Comment: Please provide an example (simplified, if appropriate) of what redundant data you are worried about having.

Comment: I edited the post, Sorry about the lack of details..

Comment: That's not an example, that's a description.  Please update your question to include actual representative sample data - sanitize it if you're worried about confidentiality.

Comment: Why use either model when SQL Server has `hierarchyid` sincd 2005? Point-in-time can be handled using the [temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017)introduced with SQL Server 2016 . To see the data as they were in a specific period all you need to do is add `FOR SYSTEM_TIME BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-01-01 00:00:00' `

Comment: Relatively klunky but in the past I've used update / delete triggers that upon insert/update or delete will capture the changed field values and add them to a "log" table to chronicle changes. Poor man's auditing.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I wish I could use those temporal tables but we don't have access to SQL Server 2016 yet. And even if `hierarchyid` is available, is there anything wrong with Nested Set Model?

Comment: @Oley using `hierarchyid` is only 100 times simpler to use, query, update, index. You can find parents, children, levels easily using the type's functions. With nested sets you'd have to write the queries or stored procedures for every single hierarchy you wanted to use, since table and field names can't be parameterized. You can have *multiple* `hierarchyid` columns to represent multiple hierarchies.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Wow, I didn't know that! Thanks a lot, I'll probably use it instead of the nested sets.